# Error creating a table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE employee
  (
    empno         INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ename         VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
    post          VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    gender        CHAR(1),
    citizenshipno VARCHAR(10),
    salary        NUMERIC(10,6) DEFAULT 10000,
    deptno        INT,
    CONSTRAINT ck_gender CHECK(gender IN('M','F')),
    CONSTRAINT uc_citizenshipno UNIQUE(citizenshipno),
    CONSTRAINT fk_department FOREIGN KEY(deptno) REFERENCE department(deptno)
  )
```

it says missing keyword...i need help really fast someone

Comment: And it says missing right parenthesis

Comment: Do not use comments to add further information to your question - instead, use the `edit` button (underneath the question tags) and add the information directly to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Change REFERENCE to REFERENCES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were multiple problems:

First - use `REFERENCES` instead of `REFERENCE` when creating a foreign key constraint.

Second - `salary` was defined as `numeric(10,6)` - this leaves room for only four digits to the left of the decimal point, and thus the default value of `10000` would not fit in the field as it has five digits to the left of the decimal point. I changed the definition of this column to `numeric(11,6)`.

Third - use `VARCHAR2` instead of `VARCHAR`. Oracle has stated that at some point they will change the behavior of `VARCHAR` to conform to the ANSI definition, which means that its behavior will change. Until then (which may or may not ever happen) use `VARCHAR2`.

Combining all the above together we get:

```
create table employee
 (empno int primary key,
  ename varchar2(20) not null,
  post varchar2(10) not null,
  gender char(1),
  citizenshipno varchar2(10),
  salary numeric(11,6) default 10000,
  deptno int,
  constraint ck_gender check(gender in('M','F')),
  constraint uc_citizenshipno unique(citizenshipno),
  constraint fk_department foreign key(deptno)
     references department(deptno));
```

Best of luck.

Comment: thank you man u saved me...i want to ask u a question though i couldnt get the default value thing why does it need to be (11,6)

Comment: If something is declared as `NUMERIC(10,6)` you're saying you want it to be able to hold numbers with up to 10 significant digits, with six of them to the right of the decimal point - so the largest number which could be contained in such a field would be 9999.999999, and thus 10000 won't "fit". By changing the size of the field to NUMERIC(11,6) the largest possible value which can be stored becomes 99999.999999, and thus 10000 can be stored in such a field.

Comment: ohh i got it thankyou my teacher gave me the wrong question then idiot him

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your CREATE statement:

- ```
  IS NOT NULL
  ```

should be **NOT NULL**

- ```
  REFERENCE
  ```

REFERENCE keyword is wrong, it should be **REFERENCES**

- ```
  VARCHAR data type
  ```

Better use **VARCHAR2**. From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1822),

> The VARCHAR datatype is synonymous with the VARCHAR2 datatype. To
>   avoid possible changes in behavior, always use the VARCHAR2 datatype
>   to store variable-length character strings.

- ```
  NUMERIC(10,6) DEFAULT 10000
  ```

The precision specified is incorrect. It will throw :

> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this
>   column

Because, `(10,6)` means 10 is the precision and 6 is the scale. So, you can have **4 digits before decimal**, while you have **5 significant digits** in `10000`.

Change it to :

```
NUMERIC(11,6) DEFAULT 10000
```